# How to handle multi client with winsock32

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, winsock

I am learning to make a client-server communication model through `socket` use `Winsock` (C++) in my school.

And I am facing problem how to make server serve multi client with limit resources, and my mission is handle this problem using multithreading and exploration technical and Specific here is use two function in C++ and winSock is: `select()` and `_beginthreadex()`. (with limited assumptions about resources)
If I use only `select()` function so my server only serve max `1024` client and if I use only `_beginthreadex()` so it will be limited on resources.

But I need to serve more than 4096 clients just use `select()` and `_beginthreadex()` (can not use only one of them because the above reason)

This is my struct of program use `select()`:

```
    SOCKET client[FD_SETSIZE], connSock;
    fd_set readfds, initfds; //use initfds to initiate readfds at the begining of every loop step
    sockaddr_in clientAddr;

    int nEvents, clientAddrLen;
    bool ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        client[i] = 0;  // 0 indicates available entry

    FD_ZERO(&initfds);


    //Step 5: Communicate with clients
    while (1) {
        FD_SET(listenSock, &initfds);
        for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i) {
            if (client[i] > 0) {
                FD_SET(client[i], &initfds);
            }
        }
        readfds = initfds;      /* structure assignment */      
        nEvents = select(0, &readfds, 0, 0, 0);
        if (nEvents < 0) {
            printf("\nError! Cannot poll sockets: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

        //new client connection
        if (FD_ISSET(listenSock, &readfds)) {
            clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
            if ((connSock = accept(listenSock, (sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &clientAddrLen)) < 0) {
                printf("\nError! Cannot accept new connection: %d", WSAGetLastError());
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("You got a connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr)); /* prints client's IP */
                cout << "\tconnSocket: " << (int)connSock << endl;

                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
                    if (client[i] == 0) {
                        client[i] = connSock;
                        FD_SET(client[i], &initfds);
                        break;
                    }

                if (i == FD_SETSIZE) {
                    printf("\nToo many clients.");
                    closesocket(connSock);
                }

                if (--nEvents == 0)
                    continue; //no more event
            }
        }

        //receive data from clients
        for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++) {
            if (client[i] == 0)
                continue;

            if (FD_ISSET(client[i], &readfds)) {
                ret = business(client[i]); // the function handle logic of my server
                if (ret == false ) {
                    FD_CLR(client[i], &initfds);
                    closesocket(client[i]);
                    client[i] = 0;


                }

            }
            if (--nEvents <= 0)
                continue; //no more event
        }

    }

      //Step 5: Close socket
    closesocket(listenSock);
```

With program above my server can not serve more than 4096 client. Somebody can give a solution for my problem ? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can increase FD_SETSIZE if you need to. See the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/maximum-number-of-sockets-supported-2#fd_set-and-select). You can also use [`WSAPoll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll). whose only restriction is the size of an array.

Answer (score 0):

One thread can handle 4096 as you show. That is because a FD_SET is limited to 4096 entries. However you can have multiple threads, and multiple FD_SETs.

Each thread would have its FD_SET to read from and reply, handling up to 4k clients. When the client 4097 arrives, you create a new thread to handle a new set of sockets. You'll need synchronisation around accepting and connecting. But apart from that, the thread handling the first 4k can run independently of the thread handling the next 4k clients.

A full example is out of scope. :-)